# error 1066 - Generate backup by mysqldump in mariaDb, name of duplicate views

Tags: mysql, mariadb, backup, case-sensitive, mysql-error-1066

Command to generate the backup
***mysqldump.exe --host=10.10.10.1 --protocol=tcp --user=user --password=****** --column-statistics=0 --port=3300 --default-character-set=utf8 database > c:/Temp/backup.SQL***

Generate the error:
**Got error: 1066: Not unique table/alias: 'apuracao_survey' when using LOCK TABLES**

In MariaDb, CASE-SENSITIVE=ON, which creates duplicate views:
** apuracao_survey
* APURACAO_SURVEY*

If you delete a VIEW, the two are removed, and when you create VIEW again, the database creates the two.

Comment: Exclude the views from the dump.

Comment: What operating system?  You have `c:`, yet you have `/` instead of `\`.

Comment: @marekful, and back up the separate views?

Comment: @RickJames, Local Windows 10. Server Windows 2003 R2

Comment: Were you porting _between_ Windows and non-Windows?  They have different defaults wrt case folding of table and database names.

Comment: @RickJames mysqldump was run on windows and writes to the local machine the result file.

Comment: `CASE-SENSITIVE=ON` is contrary to what Windows is like.